# Infinite loop with javascript (Angular NgFor and http request)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Problem is meanwhile I'm trying to check if one image exists on the resources server, Angular NgFor is performing its work.

I can guess, img.src performs the request, then my returns in callbacks are not returned as expected, in fact, defaultPrincipalUrl method is not returning nothing as expected, and for that reason Angular is performing the same requests again and again.

But, I don't know the way to solve it in Javascript.

The NgFor in the html looks like this.

```
<div class="formItem">
    <div *ng-for="#principal of localService.defaultPrincipals">
        <img src="{{defaultPrincipalUrl(principal)}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Where localService.defaultPrincipals is one array which contains image names.

In the Angular2 @Component class, I've the next implementation.

```
private imageExists(imageSrc, callback) {

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () { callback(imageSrc, true); };
    img.onerror = function () { callback(imageSrc, false); };

    img.src = imageSrc;
}

defaultPrincipalUrl(principal) {

    var im = IMAGE_DOMAIN + '/principal/' + principal;

    console.log(im);

    this.imageExists(im, function (imageSrc, exists) {

        console.log('RESULT: url=' + imageSrc + ', exists=' + exists);

        if (exists) {

            return imageSrc;
        } else {

             return '#';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: defaultPrincipalUrl doesn't return a value ..  the value returned by the call callback won't be propagated ( it's an async callback also ).

Answer (score 2):

Use the **async** pipe.

```
<div class="formItem">
    <div *ng-for="#principal of localService.defaultPrincipals">
        <img src="{{defaultPrincipalUrl(principal) | async}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The result of **defaultPrincipalUrl** must be a promise because the callback is async :

```
private imageExists(imageSrc, callback) {

    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () { callback(imageSrc, true); };
    img.onerror = function () { callback(imageSrc, false); };

    img.src = imageSrc;
}

defaultPrincipalUrl(principal) {

    var im = IMAGE_DOMAIN + '/principal/' + principal;

    console.log(im);

    let self_ = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    self_.imageExists(im, function (imageSrc, exists) {

        console.log('RESULT: url=' + imageSrc + ', exists=' + exists);

        if (exists) {
            resolve(imageSrc);
        } else {
            resolve('#');
        }
    });


    });

}
```

Comment: Ty for your answer Mourad Zouabi, I was looking for something like your contribution, works with Promises or something else ;). But, surprisingly, the behaviour is the same, infinite loop performs. If you want I can update #1, but code looks like to posted by you.

Comment: For more information, I was working with "2.0.0-alpha.46", thinking could be possible that features were working wrong on that version, I've upgrade to "2.0.0-beta.0", but has not been any improvement.